# Recursively change DateLastModified property of Folder to match that of file inside

Tags: vbscript

I have a number of folders, each with files inside the folder.

The structure looks something like this:

```
Folder.No.1
Folder_No_2
Folder No 3
```

and the files within are something like:

```
Folder.No.1\My.Movie.1.avi
Folder.No.1\My.Movie.1.txt

Folder_No_2\My_Movie_2.avi
Folder_No_2\My_Movie_2.jpg
Folder_No_2\My_Movie_2.txt

Folder No 3\My Movie 3.avi
```

As you can see, some folders contain `.` in the name, some contain `_` and some contain spaces.

The one consistent factor is that each folder will *always* contain an .avi file, regardless of anything else.

Therefore, how can I change the `Date Modified` date/time of the folder to match that of the .avi file contained within the folder? Is there some way I can do this by copying the `DateLastModified` from the file inside (the child) to the parent folder using VBScript?

So far I am working on something like this:

```
Function Recursion(strDirectory)
On Error Resume Next 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
Dim objFolderShellItem

For Each objFile in colFiles
If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = "AVI" Then
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objShellFolder = objShell.NameSpace(strDirectory)
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    'folder
    objFolderItem.ModifyDate = objFile.DateLastModified
    'file
    'objShellFolder.Items.Item(objFile.Name).ModifyDate = objFile.DateLastModified
    Wscript.Echo "Date of folder" & objFolder.Name & "was updated" 
End If
Next

For Each folder In objFolder.SubFolders
    Recursion(folder)  '<- recurse here
Next

Set objFso = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
set colFiles = Nothing

End Function




Call Recursion("C:\Temp")
```

but it fails when calling from command line with: `cscript CopyDateToParent.vbs`

What is it that is causing this not to work?

Comment: i do not see End For.  are you getting the error in the middle of the process, or not saying its not valid.  what is the error message?

Comment: end for is not necessary i saw the Next sorry.

Comment: fyi this is a vbs file correct? not html or asp or VBA?

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik Yes this is VBS VBScript file

Comment: "Recursive" is in the title and it is using a For loop since the beginning - and the folder structure has been provided to show that it needs to recursively search 1 level of sub-folders.

Comment: you have to code yourself here StangerThings i just made it compile

Comment: However sadly the previous answer given was not at all useful since it ignored every requirement in the original specification. It may have compiled but it actually did nothing and instead missed the entire purpose of the original question!

Comment: you didnt even have correct objects named correctly.  Then when that was fixed, you cannot use GetExtensionName on objFile.File, only objFile,  before you answer could even be started, you do not know how to even write simple code. at this point, (which i admit i missed, due to bad code) recursion is pretty simple to finalize at this point, you do not give "specs" or "requirements" at stackoverflow you give issues, questions or problems, hopefully as we walked through each error, you at least learned something

Answer (score 1):

If you are on an older system, this is how you would have handled it.

It is no longer allowed from vbs.  You will need a compiled language or possible kernel level privs to do so.

google powershell on this site , its done very easily

```
Function Recursion(strDirectory)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
Dim objFolderShellItem
Dim blnFound



blnFound = false
For Each objFile in colFiles
If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = "AVI" Then
    blnFound = true
    dtDateTime = objFile.DateLastModified
    'if you care only about one file, then you can exit for here for performance, or you have to do more logic on keep thing max date for the avi file or min.  you never said.
    ''file
    ''objShellFolder.Items.Item(objFile.Name).ModifyDate = objFile.DateLastModified
End If
Next

For Each folder In objFolder.SubFolders
    if blnFound = true Then
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        Set objShellFolder = objShell.NameSpace(strDirectory)''should be parent folder not 'folder' its in
        Set objFolderItem = objShellFolder.Self
        objFolderItem.ModifyDate = dtDateTime   ''no longer possible since around 2010
    End IF
    Recursion(folder)  '<- recurse here
Next

Set objFso = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
set colFiles = Nothing

End Function




Call Recursion("C:\Temp\")
```

Sorry i do not have any "Microsoft" system to help you

```
function GetFiles($path = $pwd) 
{ 
    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path)
    {
        if (Test-Path $item.FullName -PathType Container) 
        {
            $item.LastWriteTime = $dateToChange 
            GetFiles $item.FullName
        } 
        else 
        {   
            if($item.extension.ToUpper() -eq 'AVI')
            {
                $dateToChange = $item.LastWritten
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I see what you did there, great :) However it is using a fixed time ""1/01/2016 12:00:00 PM". Remember the date/time of the folder should match the date/time of the file contained within. Hence why I had placed "objFolder.DateLastModified = objFile.DateLastModified" in my original code.

Comment: Also, as this is to be run from a batch, MsgBox(objFile.Name) is not going to be useful here during recursion. Seems better just to "echo" the filename in the output window.

Comment: then take it out??????????????????????? and edit your time to what you wanted??????????????????????????

Comment: All looks good, but doesn't work though unfortunately. Still need Wscript.Echo objFolder.Name but when including that it throws an error (see where I changed my code above). However regardless of this line, the code still doesn't change the date on folders.